# Restriction of an ideal sheaf to a hyperplane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Z$ be a zero dimensional subscheme in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $H$ be a hyperplane. Then we have an exact sequence 
$0 \to I_Z \to I_Z(1) \to^f I_Z(1) \mid_H \to 0$. On the other hand, we another exact sequence 
$0 \to \mathcal{O}_Z \to I_Z(1) \mid_H \to^g I_{Z \cap H, H}(1) \to 0$. If we compose the surjective maps $f$ and $g$ then we get a surjection,
$I_Z(1) \to I_{Z \cap H, H}(1)$. 
My question is what will be the kernel of it ? 
I guess it will be $I_{Z^{\prime}}$, where $Z^{\prime}$ is the residue of $Z$ with respect to $H$. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Why should the first sequence be exact on the left?

Comment: consider the natural exact sequence $ 0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{O}_H(1) \to 0$. Now tensoring  it by $I_Z$  we get the above exact sequence.

Comment: What if ${\rm Tor}(I_Z, O_H) \neq 0$?

Comment: since the first map in the exact sequence after tensoring is generically injective ( out side $Z, I_Z$ is trivial), $I_Z \to I_Z(1)$ is injective.